# Basic assembly excercise I cant solve

Tags: assembly, x86

I just started learning Assembly x86 and I have to make an exercise, which I can't solve.
The idea is to make a program in which you ask the user to type in a number using Scanf. Then the program adds 1 to the number and outputs that number (so basically output = input +1).

When I use my code, the console shows me a Segmentation Fault.

The code:

```
mystring:   .asciz "name_of_the_programmer\nLast_Name\nAssignment 2:inout\nGive a number:\n"    #Creëert een stuk tekst
nrstring:   .asciz "%d"

.global main


main:

    movq        $0, %rax                                #Geeft de locatie %rdi een waarde van 0, maakt %rdi leeg
    movq        $mystring, %rdi                             #Voegt de waarde van mystring (het stuk tekst) toe aan %rdi
    call        printf                                  #Print de waarde van  %rdi
    call        inout                                   #roept inout op

inout:  

        pushq %rbp
        movq %rsp , %rbp

        subq $8, %rsp                                   #Plaatst stackPointer goed 
        leaq -8(%rbp), %rsi                             #Laad het adres in rsi

        movq $0, %rdi                                   #Maakt rdi leeg     
        movq $nrstring, %rdi                                #Verplaatst string nrstring naar rdi    (1e arg. scanf)
        movq $0, %rax                                   #Maakt RAX leeg   (2e arg. scanf)
        call scanf                                  #Roept Scanf op

        incq %rdi
        movq %rdi, %rax
        call printf

        movq %rbp, %rsp
        popq %rbp
        ret

end:
    mov         $0, %rdi                                #Maakt %rdi leeg
    call        exit                                    #Sluit het programma af
```

I am from holland so please dont worry about the comments and I apologize for my bad english.

Comment: The question is *where* is the segmentation fault? You can use a debugger to step through the program, and find the step that causes it.  Once you know which instruction causes it, you can think about *why* that instruction is doing something wrong, and fix it.  Get thee to a debugger.

Comment: @TNH You English isn't that bad. I, for example, couldn't speak a word in Dutch. However, it is generally a bad idea to user any language other than English in your source, be it code or comment. This is the perfect example: If those comments were in English, then maybe some of us could spot where your code diverged from your actual intent; or at least they'd provide some clearer clues where the SegFault might come from.